# Proper animation in Direct3D 10

Tags: animation, direct3d, throttling

I'm a beginner in d3d development and I'm stuck on my first issue. I've created a little program that draws a terrain with random heights in each vertex and a light that moves from left to right (plus basic keyboard management). Problem is the animated light is very skippy, input recognition fails pretty often and cpu usage is 50% constant (I have a dual core cpu). I thought that this issue was caused by incorrect throttling, but even after fixing the code i still have problems. My main loop is

```
int APIENTRY _tWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPTSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    HWND wndHandle;
    int width = 640;
    int height = 480;

    wndHandle = InitWindow(hInstance, width, height);
    InitDirect3D(wndHandle, width, height);
    DInputInit(hInstance, wndHandle);
    SceneSetUp();
    MSG msg = {0};
    QueryPerformanceFrequency((LARGE_INTEGER *) &perf_cnt);
    time_count = perf_cnt / fixedtic;
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *) &next_time);
    while (WM_QUIT != msg.message)
    {
        if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
            continue;
        }
        HandleInput();
        QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *) &cur_time);
        if (cur_time>next_time) {
            Render();
            next_time += time_count;
            if (next_time < cur_time)
                next_time = cur_time + time_count;
        }
    }
    ShutdownDirect3D();
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

while the Render function is

```
void Render()
{
    QueryPerformanceCounter((LARGE_INTEGER *) &curtime);
    timespan = (curtime - last_time) * time_factor;
    last_time = curtime;
    model.pD3DDevice->ClearRenderTargetView(model.pRenderTargetView, D3DXCOLOR(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    lightpos.x = (float)cos(ang) * 256.0f;
    ang += timespan * 0.5;
    lpvar->SetFloatVector((float *) lightpos);
    D3DXMatrixLookAtLH(&V, &model.campos, new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f), new D3DXVECTOR3(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f));
    D3DXMATRIX VP = V*P;
    camvar->SetFloatVector((float *)model.campos);
    ViewProjection->SetMatrix((float *) &VP);
    for(UINT p=0; p < techniqueDescription.Passes; ++p)
    {
        pTechnique->GetPassByIndex(p)->Apply(0);
        model.pD3DDevice->DrawIndexed(numIndices, 0, 0);
    }
    model.pSwapChain->Present(0, 0);
}
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I nailed it and I think I deserve a punch in my face. I was creating a reference device instead of a hardware device

Answer (score 0):

Remove the continue from after the Dispatch message.  As it stads if you have a shed load of messages queued up (say you move the mouse over the window) then you will end up wasting time processing those messages instead of rendering.

It would also be usual to do the following to process all the messages in a one'r:

```
    while(PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }
```

It would be interesting to see what sort of input you are handling too as you appear to be handling the input more regularly than you are rendering.

In general, though, its better to render constantly and simply multiply any movement code by the time since the last frame to smooth things out.  This way you'd work out what the movement for a given second.  So if you want to press a key and rotate at 1 rotation per second then you would simply set the rotation increment to (2 * pi) / sinceLastFrame ...

The reason your CPU time is at 50% is because you are, effectively, sitting in a loop.  You don't give up your timeslice at any point.  You simply spin round the loop handling input, probably many more times per second than rendering occurs.

Comment: My input handle is pretty simple. I'm just checking if the arrow keys have been pressed

I'm checking the input more often because I want to draw a specific amount of frames per second but I do not want to loose any input. My question arises from the fact that my app is very slow. The move animation is not fluid, but jumps around. I've seen some examples from directx sdk tutorials and the animations are always fluid and cpu usage is minimum even if they are running a loop and I can't understand (yet) what makes the code tick

Comment: @Patrik: Are you taking into account time deltas between key presses?  You are probably not and, more so, are probably checking key inputs a different amount of times every frame.  This will give horridly jerky movement.  Also keypress messages are likely to starve out the rendering process as you continually process key down messages rather than doing any rendering.

Comment: No, I'm not. I simply check if the left or right arrow keys were pressed and increment/decrement a value accordingly. From this value I compute a new camera position. However I don't think this is the issue. The light I mentioned above was jumping around (when it should move fluidly) even before I've added the HandleInput() function. I've uploaded my project [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/9287376/dxtest.zip) if someone wants to take a look

Comment: @Patrik: So what happens if you remove the continue?  Also what happens if you do that AND call Render every pass through the loop?

Comment: That was my first version. Still jumpy

Comment: @Patrik: Most probably it is jumpy because you aren't taking a frame to frame time delta to calculate how much it should move by.

Comment: I am. The timespan variable in Render() holds that delta